# Solving the inconsistent dependency location in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

So I am building a gradle project, here's my (simplified) build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release-local/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:docbook-reference-plugin:0.2.4'
    }
}
```

This gives me error:

```
   > Could not find org.apache.xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.pom
       - https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release-local/org/apache/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.build.gradle:docbook-reference-plugin:0.2.4
```

Apparently docbook requires xerces as a dependency.

So I searched for xerces in maven repository, found xerces not in `org/apache/xerces/` but in `xerces/`!!! (wtf!?) (see https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/)

So now, how should I let gradle know that when searching for the xerces for docbook, it should go to `xerces/` instead of `org/apache/xerces/`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Github page](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/docbook-reference-plugin) for that plugin, looks like the correct repository is:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
}
```

And indeed, it contains the [artifact](https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/apache/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/)

#### Previous answer

<s>Try adding `mavenCentral()` to the list of repositories</s>

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release-local/' }
}
```

Comment: Error still. gradle is still trying to find xerces in mavenCentral() with `org/apache/xerces` instead of `xerces`

Comment: > Could not find org.apache.xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.pom
       - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.pom
       - https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release-local/org/apache/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.pom

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend your set of repositories with

```
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
```

Defining URLs of repositories are not needed, except cases where you are in a corporate environment where internet access is restricted.